# Phonegap geolocalization plugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing an app through phonegap, I've add the geolocalization plugin and it's working, the problem is if I run the application through phongapp desktop the localization  works, but if i compile and generate the apk the localization doesn't work. Here is the js code:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />';
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

confirm!

check the permission on platform/android/androidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```